# is there a way to find these hrefs with my code without finding all hrefs that match my if statement?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

here is the html: `<ul class="turbolink_scroller" id="container"><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/s9cqv86tx/mvduilkn8"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184910/vi/XqTrMgSbEMo.jpg" alt="Xqtrmgsbemo" /><div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/s9cqv86tx/mvduilkn8">Woven Hooded Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/s9cqv86tx/mvduilkn8">Green</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/s9cqv86tx/yfc69h4xd"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184907/vi/2QzvRTY6rdY.jpg" alt="2qzvrty6rdy" /><div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/s9cqv86tx/yfc69h4xd">Woven Hooded Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/s9cqv86tx/yfc69h4xd">Black</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/ev3enjhr0/ebrve9hwg"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185498/vi/6WyRqFHLTT4.jpg" alt="6wyrqfhltt4" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/ev3enjhr0/ebrve9hwg">Supreme®/Schott® Fringe Suede Coat</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/ev3enjhr0/ebrve9hwg">Red</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/ev3enjhr0/phlxzfwgu"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185520/vi/9bnJYqcxXgg.jpg" alt="9bnjyqcxxgg" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/ev3enjhr0/phlxzfwgu">Supreme®/Schott® Fringe Suede Coat</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/ev3enjhr0/phlxzfwgu">Black</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/j7gw2q0fp"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185015/vi/aqugEVgfKuc.jpg" alt="Aqugevgfkuc" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/j7gw2q0fp">Grid Taping Velour Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/j7gw2q0fp">Blue</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/d2aym3g0v"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184987/vi/P9Fe5r2mdAQ.jpg" alt="P9fe5r2mdaq" /><div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/d2aym3g0v">Grid Taping Velour Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/d2aym3g0v">Off-White</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/y6phf5mlb"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184975/vi/ePxAOa6h7Fc.jpg" alt="Epxaoa6h7fc" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/y6phf5mlb">Grid Taping Velour Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/y6phf5mlb">Red</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/i3u9g5krx"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185001/vi/dYtK4tzVOzI.jpg" alt="Dytk4tzvozi" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/i3u9g5krx">Grid Taping Velour Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/e6o5y7tj2/i3u9g5krx">Black</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/o0ml2ikc9"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184895/vi/h7A3WqVrbAg.jpg" alt="H7a3wqvrbag" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/o0ml2ikc9">Track Half Zip Pullover</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/o0ml2ikc9">Tan Glen Plaid</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/i9ukqmivb"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184893/vi/bc4gd2MK45U.jpg" alt="Bc4gd2mk45u" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/i9ukqmivb">Track Half Zip Pullover</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/i9ukqmivb">Black</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/d7igbl05j"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184897/vi/6CKTR-_PTHA.jpg" alt="6cktr  ptha" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/d7igbl05j">Track Half Zip Pullover</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g2emcal6f/d7igbl05j">Red Glen Plaid</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/t320rajnf/bw5h1d8f2"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184903/vi/q4W_U311s5s.jpg" alt="Q4w u311s5s" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/t320rajnf/bw5h1d8f2">Checks Embroidered Denim Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/t320rajnf/bw5h1d8f2">Black</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/t320rajnf/r7q9edzxo"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/184900/vi/cv8DExfCW2U.jpg" alt="Cv8dexfcw2u" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/t320rajnf/r7q9edzxo">Checks Embroidered Denim Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/t320rajnf/r7q9edzxo">Blue</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/izjfmkdlo"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185094/vi/zxcLTiugvd4.jpg" alt="Zxcltiugvd4" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/izjfmkdlo">Supreme Team Puffy Jacket </a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/izjfmkdlo">Purple</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/w7wvq3nsh"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185030/vi/XETfm_tFmoQ.jpg" alt="Xetfm tfmoq" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/w7wvq3nsh">Supreme Team Puffy Jacket </a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/w7wvq3nsh">Teal</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/od5k1ra7z"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185120/vi/oD4lVboAALs.jpg" alt="Od4lvboaals" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/od5k1ra7z">Supreme Team Puffy Jacket </a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/od5k1ra7z">Black</a></div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/evtzfp2x3"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/185060/vi/RJXCXu1j6oU.jpg" alt="Rjxcxu1j6ou" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/evtzfp2x3">Supreme Team Puffy Jacket </a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/q6z0e81ft/evtzfp2x3">Gold</a></div></div></li></ul>`

this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQRvx.png) shows which hrefs im trying to get with this code:

```py
req = requests.get(mainUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
keywords = "Schott"
colors = "Black"
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='name-link', href=True):
    if keywords and colors in a.text:
        print(a['href'])
```

i only want the hrefs for the Schott Black item.  if i use `if keywords in a.text:` im left with the 2 different hrefs for Schott items, one being black and the other green.  when using `if keywords and colors in a.text:` it finds the Schott hrefs and every other href containing "Black".  how can i exclude the other "colors" hrefs that are not also the "keywords" hrefs?

Comment: nest the `if` statements

Comment: Please share the HTML which is returned by requests, as text.

Comment: does this come from an actual page?  if so, why not link to it?  soup can be used with css selectors and those are best first tuned on an actual live page.

Comment: yes this comes from a page, the reason im using the above method is because the page could change and also my keywords and colors may change depending on the item i am looking for

site is: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/

mainUrl = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets"

Answer (score 1):

You were close just change the if condition.

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='name-link', href=True):
    if (keywords in a.text) and (colors in a.text):
        print(a['href'])
```

Sample Html.

```
html='''<a class="name-link" href="#1">Schott </a>
<a class="name-link" href="#2">Black</a>
<a class="name-link" href="#3">Schott Black</a>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
keywords = "Schott"
colors = "Black"
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='name-link', href=True):
    if (keywords in a.text) and (colors in a.text):
        print(a['href'])
```

Comment: this seems to return no hrefs at all

Comment: @DominickParente : You have not posted sample html.If your html like this it should work with my code.

Comment: the hrefs are in 2 separate Divs, you can see in the image i uploaded

Answer (score 1):

```
hrefs = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('a.name-link')
           if all((keywords in a.text, colors in a.text))]
```

Comment: so print(hrefs) ? returns [ ]

Answer (score 0):

i was able to find my matching hrefs and output the correct one:

```py
req = requests.get(mainUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
keywords = "Woven"
colors = "Green"
for kw in soup.find_all('a', 'name-link', href=True):
    if keywords in kw.text:
        for c in soup.find_all('a', 'name-link', href=True):
            if colors in c.text:
                if kw['href'] == c['href']:
                    print(kw['href'])
```